# Expose particular fields in WCF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, c#-4.0

I've a class

```
[DataContract]
public class Sample 
{
   [DataMember]
   int a;
   [DataMember]
   int b;
   [DataMember]
   int c;
}

Sample sampleMethod1 ()
{
  return new Sample { a =5, b=6 }
}

Sample sampleMethod1 ()
{
  return new Sample { a =15, c=61 }
}
```

Now I want when my external customers call sampleMethod1 then the visible fields of sample class are a and c not b. similarly in sampleMethod2

Comment: It sounds like you want to return *different* classes from each method. Can you give more information about why some fields should "disappear" when objects are returned by particular methods?

Comment: It is not possible, because you are sharing a complete contract of `Sample` class with your external customers. So you should probably split it into two different interfaces/classes.

Comment: I am afraid you may need to create 2 class to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

you need something like this..

```
  [DataContract]
  [KnownType(typeof(SampleDerived1))]
  [KnownType(typeof(SampleDerived2))]
  public class Sample
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int a;
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class SampleDerived1 : Sample
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int b;
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class SampleDerived2 : Sample
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int c;
  }
```

and your methods should be like this..

```
Sample sampleMethod1 ()
{
  return new SampleDerived1{ a =5, b=6 }
}

Sample sampleMethod2 ()
{
  return new SampleDerived2{ a =15, c=61 }
}
```